# How can I pass data AND serve an html file from the server to the client?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-development-server

When user clicks "log in", an end point is triggered on the server in which a token is passed to the client. I also want to navigate the user to the main screen after clicking log in. 
How can I achieve both: 
 1. send a token variable 
    res.send(JSON.stringify(tokenVar));
 2. navigate the user
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/fileToSend.html');

When I have both of those in my endpoint at the same time, the token is sent but the screen doesn't navigate. I also tried using window.location.href = 'URL';
and I see the token print in the console, and then the window also navigates. HOWEVER, the console clears out right away and I lose access to the token variable (maybe because the new view has a different js file controlling it?).

Comment: cookies, probably. Or is the login endpoint supposed to be triggered via ajax? (In which case, navigating the user to a HTML file makes no sense). It's not really clear what the scenario is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Jush do the redirect in the client site.
The api will return this object for example:

```
{
  token:"12345",
  urltoredirect: "http://foo.com"
}
```

And then your client app will save the token at the local storage and after that will navigate the app to the urltoredirect value.